# AngularJS ng-repeat with isotope and AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs, jquery-isotope

I get data with ajax, then i need to display it in my view and use isotope on DOM elements which i get with ng-repeat. So, i need to call $scope.$apply(); Then i get error: "digest already in progress".

I tried to use "safe-apply", but scope's phase is always digest, so apply do not fires. All i need is sort of callback of ng-repeat.

Now i have something like this:

```
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/web/main/json'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.cards = data.cards;

        /* without this apply my DOM elements would be 
        invisible (if i use isotope on them)*/
        $scope.$apply(); 
        mainFunction(); // here i use isotope on my DOM elements
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("fail " + data);
    });
```

Comment: What does mainFunction() do?

Comment: Something like this:

$("#container).isotope(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your approach. Read about directives and write directive **apply-isotope** that applies isotope to children of tag it is used in and then create something like:

```
<tag1 apply-isotope>
  </tag2 ng-repeat="card in cards">
    ...
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Comment: sorry for such a late approval:)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$http({method: 'GET',
   url: '/web/main/json',
   **headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}**
   }).success(){}).error(function () {});
```